# string variables not passing to js function from php

Tags: javascript, php, variables

I'm having a few issues that I am unable to solve.

This is part of a messaging script which mostly works apart from a few Javascript sections. One in particular is the one listed below. The PHP/HTML code pulls the messages from the db and displays them in the members inbox.

Ticking on the subjects should change the color of the text to mark as read. the `onclick` function in within the `A` tag should send variables to the `markAsRead()` function so it can run a PHP script from within the function and update the db to mark the message as read.

This is an old script from about 10 years ago which I am trying to bring up to date so I can use it again. I have removed some of the less important div tags to make the code smaller for here.

```
<?php
$my_id = $_SESSION['memberID'];
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM private_messages WHERE to_id ='$my_id' AND recipientDelete ='0' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 100");
$msgcount = 0;
if ($stmt->execute(array('recipientDelete'))) {
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        $tdate = $row['time_sent'];
        $date = date_create($tdate);    
        $fromName = $row['fromName'];
        $frID = $row['from_id'];
        $Subj = $row['subject'];
        if($row['opened'] == "0"){
            $textWeight = 'msgDefault';
        } else {
            $textWeight = 'msgRead';
        }
$msgcount++;        
?>
        <div class="line">
            <div class="s-12 l-five">
                <div class="box chkBox"><input name ="toggle" id ="toggle1" type ="checkbox"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="s-12 l-five">
            <div class="box"><span class="toggle"><a class="<?php echo $textWeight; ?>" id="subj_line_<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="markAsRead(<?php $row['id']; ?>)"><?php echo stripslashes($row['subject']); ?></a></span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php
    }
    // If you have no messages then post the msg below
    if($msgcount < 1){
            echo '<div class="s-12 m-6 l-12"><h4 align="center">Your Inbox is empty</h4></div>';
    }   
}
?>
</form>
    <div class="margin-bottom">   
        </div>
```

Here is the function which I am having troubles with.

```
function markAsRead(msgID){  
  $.post("markAsRead.php",{messageid:msgID, ownerid:<?php echo $my_id; ?>},function(data){
      $('#subj_line_'+msgID).addClass("msgRead");
  });
}
```

Comment: You haven't yet stated what it should do, and what it isn't doing.

Comment: I thought I gave a pretty detailed description above the code, did you not read it?

Comment: My apologies for not reading correctly about what it should do. I do however fail to see where your code is running into issues, as it isn't yet reproducible. Is there an error that the function throws?

Comment: when i click on the 'subject text' to open the message in the inbox, nothing happens but you can see it is an active link. it is meant to change the colour of the text to show the message has been read and at the same time it should update the database to show the message has been read. I get no errors at all.

Comment: if i add alert(data); after the line $('#subj_line_'+msgID).addClass("msgRead"); it opens a blank alert box, no text, nothing at alll

Comment: And if you open the console in your browser and click the link, then what does it say?

Comment: nothing happens, no errors and no warnings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `onclick` attribute you are missing an `echo` keyword. This means that the variable is not rendered into the HTML and therefor not showing up in your JavaScript function. Changing the attribute to the line below should fix the problem.

```
onclick="markAsRead(<?php echo $row['id']; ?>)"
```

Comment: how did I miss the echo? I should have seen that. yes it works how it should now. much appreciated